# Binding MatRadioGroup to enum with ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, angular-material

I'd like to use the Angular Material Radio Module to allow users the selection of an enum value.

```js
export enum MyType {
    TypeA = "TypeA",
    TypeB = "TypeB",
    TypeC = "TypeC"
}
```

I've exposed the enum in the code behind so I can bind to it in the HTML:

```js
public MyType = MyType;
public selectedType: MyType = MyType.TypeA; // set default
```

And for the HTML I'm trying to use mat-radio-group as described in the docs:

```html
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Choose Type" [(ngModel)]="selectedType">
    <mat-radio-button [value]="MyType.TypeA">Type A</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button [value]="MyType.TypeB">Type B</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button [value]="MyType.TypeC">Type C</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Unfortuantely this results in following error on the [(ngModel)] binding

> Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'MyType'.

Can this be achieved using enums?

Comment: can't reproduce this with the code you shared, the error must be somewhere else, try adding more details to your question

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-export-excel-xlsx-e7ycj4?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html